# How do I find all directories that contain matching files?

Tags: find

I am looking for directories that contain files that match a pattern, say, `foobar*.csv`.
Directories that do contain such files may contain hundreds of them (and *no subdirectories*!), so I want find to print `here/is/the/path/to/dir` as soon as it finds `here/is/the/path/to/dir/foobar-2022-01-01.csv` and stop descending.

How do I do that?

Comment: sounds like a job for a proper programming or scripting language, and not for `find` + shell scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type f -name "foobar*.csv" -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u
```

Explanation:

- Find all the files that meet the "foobar*.csv" pattern.
- Get the dirname for each file.
- Sort them unique.

This isn't memory efficient, but for "hundreds" of files it'll take a few milliseconds to get you the result.

Comment: it took almost 2 minutes (on a remote directory) but it works, thanks!

Comment: With GNU `find`, you can make it (orders of magnitude) more efficient and more robust with `LC_ALL=C find /path/to/base/dir -type f -name "foobar*.csv" -printf '%h\0' | LC_ALL=C sort -zu | tr '\0' '\n'`. In any case, it doesn't satisfy the OP's requirement of *stopping at first match* and *not recursing*.

Comment: There isn't any general purpose tool that stops at first match. The requirement can't be satisfied but by a custom program.

Comment: `-exec dirname -- {} +` would be faster

Answer (score 0):

With zsh:

```
dirs=( **/*(/e['()(($#)) $REPLY/foobar*.csv(NY1)']) )
```

That doesn't prevent descending in that it will still try to find subdirs of matching dirs, `Y1` will stop at the first match of `foobar*.csv`, but zsh will still need to read the full contents of all (non-hidden) directories to find subdirectories).

Answer (score 0):

With the (POSIX-like) [`bosh` shell](https://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html), where `find` (actually [`sfind`](https://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/sfind.1.html)) is builtin and has some `-call`/`-calldir` predicates that can evaluate shell code:

```
find_match() {
  find . ! -name . -prune -name "$1" -call 'pwd; return' ';'
  false
}
find . -type d -calldir 'find_match "foobar*.csv"' ';' -prune
```

To do anything with those matching directories, add a:

```
-call '
  dir=$1
  whatever you need to do with "$dir"
' {} ';'
```

To that command above.

`-prune` like in standard `find` is what stops `find` from descending into subdirectories. AFAICT, `sfind` doesn't have a GNU-style `-quit` or NetBSD-style `-exec [status]`, but it looks like calling `return` from a `-call[dir]` called within a function can achieve the same effect and makes it even more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` to find all directories, and for each directory, try to expand the given globbing pattern.  If the pattern is expanded to something that exists, print the directory path and don't descend further.

```bash
find . -type d \
    -exec sh -c 'set -- "$1"/foobar*.csv; [ -e "$1" ]' sh {} \; \
    -print -prune
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `find`'s `-execdir` option instead of `-exec`:

```
find . -iname 'foobar*.csv' -execdir sh -c 'pwd' {} +
```

This uses a `sh -c` wrapper around `pwd` (instead of just running `-execdir pwd {} +`) because `pwd` doesn't take filename args and will complain if given them. The shell wrapper allows pwd to be run in a directory without passing the filename args to it.

Alternatively, if there is any chance that there might be more matching files in a directory than will fit into ARG_MAX (about 2MB on Linux so this is very unlikely), pipe the output into `uniq`.

```
find . -iname 'foobar*.csv' -execdir sh -c 'pwd' {} + | uniq
```

NOTE: `-execdir` is a non-standard enhancement to the POSIX `find` command. It may be missing on some versions of `find` (especially ancient and/or proprietary versions).  It **is** available in both GNU find and BSD find.